# Running multiple CMD in dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, docker, devops

I have a requirement to run both the Mock API and UI of a reactjs application. Can i use something like

```
CMD /usr/src/api/ npm start ; /usr/src/app/ npm start
```

after npm install of the respective package.json files.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah, you can. Just make sure both of them are running on different ports.

Comment: I would recommend to have two containers which are running in swarm network driver, so that they both can connect together, its not recommended to have multiple processes running inside a single container but there are ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible, a solution with two containers would actually be simpler:

since `npm start` is probably blocking, it would need to be put to background, otherwise you wouldn't be able to run the second `npm start`. But putting the servers to the background would end up stopping the container as there would be no foreground process running anymore and the container would exit.

So, in adddition to having to background them, you would have to add a way to make the container not exit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I even tried running the Mock_API npm start at the background and the UI part using the CMD command. But still only the UI part is getting loaded and the API is not. 

I am like wondering what could be the option to run this. 

In addition to this running in two seperate containers , may i know how do we link them ???

Comment: you can put them in the same network using `--network <network_name>`. `docker-compose` will do this automatically for you

Comment: Thanks for your response Uku Loskit. Can you please help me with an example.